# Need a word-list generator from a few words and numbers

Tags: passwords, recovery

I have an old rar backup and I am trying to recover the password. I remember the words in the password, but I usually add some numbers and cap some characters (don't know which ones though). I have been trying for days to use a recovery tool to work on it. Most tools have a dictionary option, but they do not combine the words and numbers into permutations . I need to generate some possible passwords base on about 8 words and 1-9, then run the generated list through a recovery app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome, are you asking for a tool or technique to do that?

Comment: I am using a dictionary attack tool and technique. Was looking for a way to generate the dictionary.

Comment: Questions like this (yes, you're not the only one) are typically solved by writing a custom application or script.

Comment: just found this - may do the trick http://textmechanic.com/Combination-Generator.html

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to extract the password hash with [rar2john](http://www.cybercrimetech.com/2014/07/how-to-cracking-zip-and-rar-protected.html), then go with a mask attack with [oclhashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) cracking with your GPU to gain some speed. It works well on windows.

simple example with masking:
say you know the password contains the string 'password' but the two numbers that follow are unknown. Then, the masking part of the command will look like this:

```
command: -a 3 password?d?d
keyspace: password00 - password99
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good generators available. 
Crunch is one worth trying 
https://pentestlab.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/creating-wordlists-with-crunch/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program that comes with Kali linux called [Crunch](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch) to create a custom dictionary.

The syntax for Crunch is;

```
crunch <min-len> <max-len> [<charset string>] [switch]
```

The `-t` switch can be used to add your string into the dictionary.

> [-t @,%^] is optional and allows you to specify a pattern, eg: @@god@@@@ where the only the @'s, ,'s, %'s, and ^'s will change. null  null@ will insert lower case characters
>
> , will insert upper case characters
>
> % will insert numbers
>
> ^ will insert symbols

You can have a look at the manual and full syntax for Crunch [here](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-r1-man-pages/crunch).

Answer (score -1):

`github.com/adaywithtape/wlm` adds subtracts words, prefixes, suffixes, cleans, optimizes. Whatever you want it to do.